# Azure Service Bus Emulator

Tags: azure, emulation, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I am developing a `WebJob`, which uses service bus queue, but I don't have an Azure account.

Does there exist some `Service Bus` emulator to test the webjob ?
I need to take the queue input to simulate the `[ServiceBusTrigger]`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no Service Bus emulator.
A feedback on UserVoice is open at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/2565564-provide-a-service-bus-emulator-on-a-local-computer and a GitHub issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/223.
Don't hesitate to upvote and subscribe to these feedback channels.

However, the Azure Storage Emulator includes an emulator for Azure Storage queues if this can be an alternative: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/

If your run your Web Job code locally, the WebJob trigger might be able to connect to the local Azure Storage Emulator. Please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk/#workerrole

Comment: WebJob has two attributes to receive queues messages [QueueTrigger] and [ServiceBusTrigger], if I use storage emulator I will receive the first attribute.

Comment: If your run your Web Job code locally with the Azure Web Job SDK, it might work but I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 13):

This has been a long-standing issue, so I think it's worthwhile to offer an update to the state of things right now.

There isn't a local emulator available for Azure Service Bus yet, however some people have started upvoting [this github ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/223) on the Azure Service Bus project.

If you've landed on this issue and are looking for an emulation option, I urge you to put your upvote on the original problem description.