# How do I Work with Azure ServiceBus Locally

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azureservicebus

I have a server that communicate with clients via ServiceBus,
Now I got a new requirement that server should work also with local clients(without Ethernet connection).
There is any way to run AzureServiceBus locally?

Comment: It is not possible. See [Azure Service Bus Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178656/azure-service-bus-emulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want some feature like service bus emulator, you could vote for the advice on the azure feedback page: [Service Bus emulator on a local computer](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/35371870-provide-a-service-bus-emulator-on-a-local-computer) and the github issue [Local development](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/223).

And If you want to use the Brokered Messaging capabilities (Queues, Topics and Subscriptions) then you could use [Service Bus for Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/service-bus-archive/dn282142(v=azure.100)), which will allow you to test locally. However this has reached the [Mainstream Support End Date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/17012).